# How to handle events of HTML elements in DJANGO

Tags: asp.net, django

Need to know how handle `ontextchanged` /`onChange` events of HTML elements in `DJANGO`.

Like in `ASP.NET` we would simply call a server side function which needs to be executed whea an event is triggered.
for e.g

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                           ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged**"></asp:TextBox>
```

Is there a similar way in DJANGO to hadle these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent in Django framework. You have to write your own Javascript code to detect changes and then send an AJAX request. It can be easily handled with jQuery library.

**E.g** :

```js
$('#TextBox1').change(function() {
  alert('input value changed : ' + $(this).val());
  $.ajax({
    url: "yourserver.com/path/", // endpoint
    type : "POST", // HTTP method
    data: $(this).val() // data sent
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="TextBox1" type="text" value="stack overflow" />
```

Read [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and [`Jquery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation for more information